# $|g(t_0)-p|≤|g(t)-p|$ implies that $g'(t_0) \cdot [g(t_0)-p] =0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here's a homework problem I'm struggling with.

Suppose $g$ : $(a,b) \to \Bbb{R}^n$ is a differentiable parameterized curve and that for some $p$ we have $|g(t_0)-p| ≤ |g(t)-p|$. Prove  that  $g'(t_0)\cdot(g(t_0)-p) =0$. Give a geometric explanation.

By using the definition of the euclidean norm I ended up with:

$g'(t_0)\cdot(g(t_0)-p) ≤ g'(t) \cdot (g(t)-p)$

but I don't know where to go with that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $|g(t_0)-p| \leq |g(t)-p|$ geometrically says that $g(t_0)$ is closer to $p$ than any other point on the curve. Try drawing a few curves and you will see that in 2D, the only way to have a point on a curve closest to some $p$ is if the line from $p$ to the closest point on the curve makes a right angle with the curve at that point. (Here we are assuming $g' \neq 0$ to avoid kinks in the curve).

Now lets get to the math. Instead of using $|g(t)-p|$, lets use $|g(t)-p|^2 = (g(t)-p) \cdot (g(t)-p)$.
The assumptions imply that $f(t):= (g(t)-p) \cdot (g(t)-p)$ is differentiable and has a minimum at $t=t_0$.
Thus $f'(t_0)=0$. Compute $f'(t)$ and plug in $t_0$ and you will have your answer.

Comment: How exactly do you know that f'($t_0$) is 0?

Comment: If a differentiable real function on an interval attains a minimum at a point, then its derivative is zero at the point. This is a fact you should remember from calculus 1.

Comment: yes, but if you have f(x)= x on [1,3] there is a minimum at x=1, but the derivative isn't 0. So how do we know in this case that the derivative there is 0?

Comment: @MathNoob, your question assumed that $f$ is defined on an open interval, you are correct that I should have specified this in my previous statement.

Comment: I just noticed that before you commented. I get it all now. Thank!